# MAC OS - Wine - Unknown heap type?

Tags: c#, macos, exception, runtime-error, wine

I have installed Wine in MAC OS according to this link,

https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/

It gets installed. But when running the installed program from Terminal `wine program.exe` I get this error message,

```
Unknown heap type: SmartAssembly


Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in .: (): IL_0005: bne.un.s IL_000e


at <Module>..cctor () [0x0000a] in <1f86b0135164447e81f217c6de48d7eb>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in .: (): IL_0005: bne.un.s IL_000e


at <Module>..cctor () [0x0000a] in <1f86b0135164447e81f217c6de48d7eb>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: The only official supported way to run C# programs on Mac is .NET Core from Microsoft. For all other approaches (like Mono/Wine), nobody guarantees the results.

Comment: You mean what is in this link? https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/macos